# Change custom rewrite rule when permalink is updated/changed

Tags: plugins, php, functions, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a scenario where i need to make a rewrite rule dynamic so that when permalink is changed the re-write rule should get updated as well

```
function rewrite_rule() { 
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $post = get_post($result_id);
    $post_slug  = $post_id  ->post_name


    add_rewrite_rule('^'.$post_slug.'/([^/]*)/?','index.php?post_type=page&page_id=1234&term=$matches[1]','top');

    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true); 
} 

add_action('init', 'rewrite_rule' );
```

In this case

> $post_slug

should be the permalink slug value from wordpress and everytime user changes the permalink value the rewrite should be updated with the value as well

Comment: Can you write something more, give an example? The rewrite rule is supposed to work for one particular post or for each post?  
What is the task of the rewrite rule, something apart from setting the `term` query variable?

Comment: It is supposed to work for a post, In this case the page id 1234. what i want is to make the permalink field dynamic and then use the query variable term as a slug (as per the rewrite rule) for example; assume permalink value is "article" and i want it to be rewritten as "article/term" based on the query variable '?term' and if i change the permalink value to again "blog" then i want to the rewrite to be as "blog/term"